# Sharing set read only access to Case for Community users couldn't create a case after assignment rule triggered in apex

Tags: apex, trigger, assignment-rules, sharing-sets

- Case - OWD is private.
- Community user has read, create, edit object level permission.
- Sharing set - Read access to Case

I have a trigger helper class with sharing rule enforced.

```
void updateCaseDML(Map<Id, Case> newCases){
     
   for(Case c : [SELECT Id, Origin FROM Case Where Id :newCases.keySet()]]){
        
   //checking the record access
         UserRecordAccess  ura = [SELECT RecordId, HasReadAccess, MaxAccessLevel FROM UserRecordAccess WHERE UserId =:userId  AND RecordId =:c.id];

       **Database.DMLOptions dmo  = new Database.DMLOptions();
       dmo.assignmentRuleHeader.useDefaultRule = true;
       c.setOptions(dmo);**
       updateCaseList.add(c);
   }
   Database.upsert(updateCaseList);
}
```

In the above instance MaxAccessLevel is 'Read'  and I couldn't upsert it when assignment rule is enforced as shown above. Without the assignment rule code block user can able to create a case. Assignment rule owners are from Queue which community user don't have access.

I also noticed when I add 'UserRecordAccess.MaxAccessLevel' to the query for Case that is

```
[SELECT Id, Origin, UserRecordAccess.MaxAccessLevel FROM Case Where Id :newCases.keySet()]
```

I got MaxAccessLevel = 'Transfer' in the second query. Which was giving me 'Read' without this change. This would be an ideal fix if I knew why this is happening.

What is the root cause of this behavior? I couldn't get this sorted. Any help would be appreciated.

Note: This is a trigger helper class.